# Выполнять действия при наведении курсора мыши на QPushButton PyQt5 python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, hover, qpushbutton

**Я хочу создать событие при наведении курсора на кнопку.**

При клике всё просто:

```
def rreg():
    sound_click.play() #тут звук проигрывается
form.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(rreg)
```

**Как сделать то же самое, только клик заменить на наведение курсора?**

Comment: Тут для label (смотрите в ответе) - переделайте для Вашего случая ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456403/mouseover-event-for-a-pyqt5-label

Comment: Нашел более легкий способ:


def enter(event):
         sound_navod.play()


form.pushButton_2.enterEvent = enter


и всё работает :3

Comment: По ссылке, которую я Вам дал, это всё описано. Учитесь читать всё до конца... :) Я поэтому и дал Вам эту ссылку :)